# Quickest way to create a large file and quickest way to remove it

Tags: delphi

I am trying to make a ntfs disk unwriteable by using up all the empty space. Is there a way I can create a file and set the file size to the max size of disk and then reset it to a less value to make it writeable again? If not what is the fastest way to create a file? I am using delphi. Also the fastest way to remove it will be needed too. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious: what possible use would that serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `TFileStream` and set its size using its `Size` property. Something like this...

```
var
  F: TFileStream;
begin
  F:= TFileStream.Create('C:\BigFile', fmCreate);
  try
    F.Size:= 50000000000;
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
```

This would create a file `C:\BigFile` with a size of about 46GB.

You would still have to calculate how big of a file to create based on the amount of free space. Keep in mind that this doesn't actually write any data, it only instructs the file system that the file is a certain size.

To delete the file, just do the same only set the size to 0...

```
var
  F: TFileStream;
begin
  F:= TFileStream.Create('C:\BigFile', fmCreate);
  try
    F.Size:= 0;
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
  DeleteFile('C:\BigFile');
```

---

**EDIT**

During my test of large files, I realized that you have to use `Int64` instead of `Integer` in order to accommodate for these large sizes.

Also bear in mind that there are files constantly changing, especially on the Windows system drive. Even two sequential calls to `DiskFree` and `TFileStream.Size` could result in an error of not enough disk space available. I'd suggest to write a file for example 100MB less than the free space, then add 1MB at a time until it fails, then add 1KB at a time until it fails, then add 1 byte at a time until it fails. Then you'll know you can guarantee that all space is taken without just raising a single error and completely failing.

This would begin with something like this...

```
var
  F: TFileStream;
begin
  F:= TFileStream.Create(FILENAME, fmCreate);
  try
    F.Size:= DiskFree(3) - (1024 * 1024 * 100);
    while 1 = 1 do begin
      try
        F.Size:= F.Size + (1024 * 1024);
      except
        Break;
      end;
    end;
    while 1 = 1 do begin
      try
        F.Size:= F.Size + 1024;
      except
        Break;
      end;
    end;
    while 1 = 1 do begin
      try
        F.Size:= F.Size + 1;
      except
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
```

Note this could be constructed better (as far as error handling), but this should give you a good start.

Comment: Ok. But how would you remove them quickly without hanging the app? For this, i plan to incorporate a progress bar.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean. Removing it is another story, but you could do so by setting the file size to 0 also. And what do you mean by hanging the app and a progress bar? Have you tried my code? It's instant.

Comment: And what do you mean by hanging the app and a progress bar? I mean when I try to use deletefile for large files the app seem unresponsive for a while. I have not tried your code. I am going to now

Comment: I managed to save a 50GB file in a fraction of a second using this code. What more do you want? You don't even need a progress bar, your app won't hang. But deleting the file is simple, either `DeleteFile` or `MyStream.Size := 0`.

Comment: "to avoid a scenario where you might create a single 10TB" If I could just reset the size:=0 then why would it be an issue?

Comment: I just don't know how the filesystem would react if you did such a thing. I don't have the type of storage space to test it.

Comment: Pointless to set size to 0 and then call DeleteFile. Just do the latter.

Comment: @Jerry Don't write `while 1 = 1`. Write `while True`. Also, doing this with `TFileStream` is messy with errors. Raw Win32 API is what you want here.